# Need samples Use Case diagram

Tags: architecture

I need some sample use case diagrams of a system for the purpose of learning how to make use case diagram.

I would be glad if anyone help me out..

- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples from a free site dedicated to creating UML diagrams on the web: [http://yuml.me](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/usecase/samples)